# Check Python String Formatting

Tags: python, python-re

I can accept user's input in two formats:

1. `123`
2. `123,234,6028`

I need to write a function/a few lines of code that check whether the input follows the correct format.

**The rules:**

1. If a single number input, then it should be just a number between 1 and 5 digits long
2. If more then one number, then it should be comma-separated values, but without spaces and letters and no comma/period/letter allowed after the last number.

The function just checks if formatting correct, else it prints `Incorrect formatting, try entering again`.

I would assume I would need to use `re` module.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could do it with re, but its simple enough that a more brute force solution with `str.split`, among other options. Its not going to be a big deal either way. If you like `re`, try an implementation and come back if you need specific help.

Comment: I have a doubt regarding your comment on "no dots" after the last number. Do you want to allow floats? How?

Comment: @mozway I would not want floats. Simply numbers (in my case they are IDs) separated by commas (if it's more than 1 number). 

Thank you for you answer. 
Could you do a minor correct so that input can be only from 1 to 5 digits long?

Comment: @Alex thanks for the feedback, I updated the answer to only allow numbers of 1 to 5 digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex:

```
import re

validate = re.compile('\d{1,5}(?:,\d{1,5})*')

validate.fullmatch('123') # valid

validate.fullmatch('123,456,789') # valid

validate.fullmatch('1234567') # invalid
```

Use in a test:

```
if validate.fullmatch(your_string):
    # do stuff
else:
    print('Incorrect formatting, try entering again')
```

Comment: validate.fullmatch('1234567') matches, but shouldn't by rule 1.

Comment: @DarrylG I had misread, I updated

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```py
def validString(string):
    listofints = [v.isdigit() for v in string.split(",") if 0 < len(v) < 6]
    if not len(listofints) or not all(listofints):
        print("Incorrect formatting, try entering again.")
```

Comment: validString('1234567') should detect incorrect formatting, but doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should leave the Boolean variable `valid` as `True` if the entered ibnput complies with your rules and `False` otherwise:

```
n = input("Your input: ")
valid = True
try:
    if int(n) > 9999: 
        valid = False
except:
    for character in n:
        if not character in "0123456789,":
            valid = False
    if n[-1] == ",":
        valid = False
```

Comment: For `,,0` valid is True but should be False.